# I need to create a website that looks like this

Tags: image

[image]

I got an assignment to create a website that looks like this. I have all of the images but I am stuck.

I am a pretty rusty coder.

Some of the things I can't seem to get are.

Image cropping: how do I make it so that it shows part of an image.
Moving objects around: do I use float or grid or flex?

Overall just feeling overwhelmed. Help?

Comment: What are the requirements? What languages, frameworks, etc are you allowed to use? Finally, spend some time running through a tutorial on whatever technology you're supposed to use.

Comment: I am just supposed to use HTML and CSS

Comment: See [ask], you have to get started and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Good test project I would recommend you get you requirements on this down first, like ACVM stated then you have to also consider your strength on this requirement the break down to sprints and chunks/milestones before you start coding.
Language I would recommend for easy development:
php - to handle mailing and contact us
html5 and css5 - creating the layout/design (preferably bootstrap check wrapbootstrap.com and startbootstrap.com)

Comment: Thanks. I am just supposed to use HTML and CSS to create it. Its pretty overwhelming when looking it as a whole

Comment: @Hype it's overwhelming if you don't break it up into chunks, start with the top tool bar with the logo on the left and 2 buttons on the right. Next add the main banner image of the house, then add an empty section after that with just the text, then shift that text over and add the map image, then shift the text up and add a Register Now button. Just go at it piecemeal. Something that helps me is to actually draw squares around components and larger squares around "shared" components until you get up to 1 big one for the entire page <- that'll mimic your page hierarchy.

Comment: Do you know how to only show one portion of an image using CSS?

Comment: well a simple search on google would get u numerous answer on showing a part of an image